# EF Core - One to many relationship with additional navigation property of same dependent entity type

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-relationship

I'm having trouble configurating my relationships in EF Core. I've been greeted with the following exception -

> Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
> FOREIGN KEY constraints

I've trimmed back the entities for this post, but both of these entities have their own table.

```
public class ApplicationSetupTest
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid SchemeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Guid LatestVersionId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationSetupVersionTest LatestVersion { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ApplicationSetupVersionTest> VersionHistory { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationSetupVersionTest
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid SetupId { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string AuditComment { get; set; }
    public Guid PreviousVersionId { get; set; }
}
```

The `ApplicationSetupTest` class effectively defines static data with a `LatestVersionId` that is the key for navigation property `LatestVersion`.

The `ApplicationSetupVersionTest` class is the versioned/audited data. Each one of these has a `SetupId` to link it back to the `ApplicationSetupTest` to which is refers.

I added the `VersionHistory` property purely for this post to demonstrate that there could be multiple `ApplicationSetupVersionTest` on every `ApplicationSetupTest`. I haven't added an `ApplicationSetupTest` on the `ApplicationSetupVersionTest` as this isn't something I expect to need.

My configuration for `ApplicationSetupTest` is then as follows:

```cs
public class ApplicationSetupEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationSetupTest>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationSetupTest> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(t => t.SchemeId).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(t => t.Description).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(t => t.LatestVersionId).IsRequired();

        builder.HasMany(t => t.VersionHistory)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.SetupId)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.HasOne(t => t.LatestVersion)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<ApplicationSetupTest>(t => t.LatestVersionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.HasOne<Scheme>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.SchemeId)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

The `HasMany` -> `WithOne` on `VersionHistory` is there to define that when I delete a setup, I should delete all version entities.

I assume the second configuration is therefore the area to change. The `OnDelete(NoAction)` was added following Google searches and I also tried removing the `IsRequired()` as well as making the `LatestVersionId` nullable.

I am looking to configure the second relationship so that the `LatestVersion` property can be included on query.

Any thoughts out there on how to configure such a relationship? Or am I doing something that you wouldn't recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I will refer to the models as `Setup` and `Version` for simplicity).

With your one-to-many configuration -

```cs
builder.HasMany(t => t.VersionHistory)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.SetupId)
    .IsRequired();
```

you have declared `Setup` as the principal end, and `Version` as the dependent end, which is correct.

But then you have a `LatestVersionId` foreign key in `Setup`, referencing to `Version`, and configuration of the one-to-one relationship -

```cs
builder.HasOne(t => t.LatestVersion)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<ApplicationSetupTest>(t => t.LatestVersionId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
    .IsRequired();
```

trying to configure `Setup` as the dependent end and `Version` as the principal end. I'm sure you can see the contradiction.

With the following simplified models -

```cs
public class Setup
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Version LatestVersion { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Version> VersionHistory { get; set; }
}

public class Version
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }        
    public string Data { get; set; }

    // not nullable - every Version must belong to a Setup
    public Guid SetupIdHistory { get; set; }

    // nullable - not every Version is a latest version
    public Guid? SetupIdLatest { get; set; }
}
```

you can configure them correctly to represent your relationships as -

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Setup> builder)
{
    builder.HasMany(p => p.VersionHistory)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.SetupIdHistory)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)  // not required, cascading is default
        .IsRequired();

    builder.HasOne(p => p.LatestVersion)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<Version>(p => p.SetupIdLatest)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
        .IsRequired(false);
}
```

If you choose not to have a foreign key for the one-to-many relationship, EF will create a nullable one for you and manage the relationship at model level with a shadow property. But for the one-to-one relationship, you must define a foreign key.

```cs
public class Version
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }        
    public string Data { get; set; }

    // nullable - not every Version is a latest version
    public Guid? SetupId { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Setup> builder)
{
    builder.HasMany(p => p.VersionHistory)
        .WithOne()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .IsRequired();    // this will have no effect, the FK will be nullable

    builder.HasOne(p => p.LatestVersion)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<Model.Version>(p => p.SetupId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
        .IsRequired(false);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the extremely clear and easy to follow answer. I have implemented in my solution and everything works as expected. I think I've got a call to make within my own solution. EF Core and relationships aside, I feel it's unintuitive for the Version to know that it's latest via a duplicate ID, rather than the Setup defining what it's latest is. Therefore, I'll consider whether to use this or remove the relationship altogether and retrieve the LatestVersion from the DB when required based on the ID.

Comment: @JoshC From responsibility point of view, it shouldn't be `Version`'s responsibility to track itself. `Version` should contain some property/properties (e.g. date, etc) and `Setup` should decide, based on those properties, which one is the latest for itself. But that is just my perspective/opinion.