# Entity with current and historical related entity in EF Core

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I have a `Seller` and its current `Terms` ("terms and conditions" of sale). I also want to archive older terms.

```cs
public class Seller
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public Terms Terms { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Terms> TermsHistory { get; set; }
  public void Update(Terms terms) { TermsHistory.Add(Terms); Terms = terms; }
  //etc.
}

public class Terms
{
  public long SellerId { get; set; }
  public Seller Seller { get; set; }
  //etc.
}
```

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
  // Seller
  builder
    .Entity<Seller>()
    .HasKey(x => x.Id);
  builder
    .Entity<Seller>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Terms)
    .WithOne(x => x.Seller)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
    .IsRequired();
  builder
    .Entity<Seller>()
    .HasMany(x => x.TermsHistory)
    .WithOne()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
    .IsRequired();

  // Terms
  builder
    .Entity<Terms>()
    .HasKey(x => x.SellerId);
}
```

For delete behaviour: if I delete a seller, I want to delete all related terms (both current and historical).

But I get:

> The foreign key property 'Terms.SellerId1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'SellerId' exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated primary key type.

What is the correct way to do this? I'm using Postgres.

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL Server and other databases have [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) that solve this problem at its root. [EF Core 6](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2022/01/31/efcoretemporaltables/) and later supports temporal tables for SQL Server at least

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using Postgres. I will research temporal tables, sounds interesting, thanks.

Comment: I hope there's a way to do this the "old fashioned" way without temporal tables... just to keep it simple, if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, temporal tables is one area where PostgreSQL is behind other databases. This isn't something that can be solved with a single `EffectiveDate` field even if you were using SQL directly. That's why in Standard SQL, temporal tables have ValidFrom and ValidTo fields. It's harder with an ORM as TermHistory isn't a real entity, it's a version of `Term`. When you search for the Terms at a specific point in time, you're still searching for Terms.

Comment: To make things simple you'd better follow the temporal table model - use separate From and To tables, not just `EffectiveFrom`. This makes it a *lot* easier to find the valid data at a specific point in time. Use separate "current" and history tables (that's how SQL works too). You can manage the fields and rows with table-level triggers. This ensures the date fields are always valid

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos you've given me some good leads to follow.

Comment: Just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66583887/9971404), unsure yet if I can repurpose it for my use case.

Comment: Keep the `Terms` relation but remove the `TermsHistory` - if the database doesn't understand about temporal FK constraints the ORM will choke. EF Core can map to queries, views and functions though, so if you want to get the terms `AS OF` a specific time, you can create a method that queries the historical table, or a view that `UNION ALL`s the current and historical tables

Comment: That's an answer to a different question. Besides, how "simple" does this look, compared to `FROM Terms where ValidFrom>= @asof  and ValidTo < @asof` ?

Comment: @lonix, it is good case to apply TPC approach, instead of creating multiple relationships between the same entities. Just create abstract `Term` class, and two implementations, one - `EffectiveTerms` - for current/effective terms, other, let's say `HistoryTerms` for history.